# Is there any API for Text-Speech?

Tags: api, text-to-speech, speech, speech-to-text

I'm looking for a **Text-Speech API** for my project, but I couldn't find a good one, because I'm looking for free.

I have found [iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org), It's free for mobile developers but you must pay if you are a web developer.

I tried [Google Text Speech](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=google%20text%20speech%20is%20limited%20to%20100%20characters), but it's limited to 100 characters.

Do you know any **API for Text-Speech** like these?

Thanks.

Comment: What platform are you developing for?

Comment: I'm developing an user script (javascript).

Comment: Is this to run on mobile platform(s), via web brower(s), metro or another JavaScript host?

Comment: It's only for web browser, just like browser extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this [The Javascript API](http://www.speechapi.com/apis/javascript/)  for text to speech using javascript